# Issue with User Credentials in Sandbox

Tags: salesforce-id

Have you seen this issue before ?

1. Create a User.
2. Receives an email for SSO Login. Ignores the email.
3. Resets Password for the User, Sets password.
4. Open any other browser, puts username password, test.salesforce.com
5. Error Thrown : Invalid Credentials.
6. Tries Forgot Password – Never Receives Password Email (No Email Log As well)

Few Pointers : 
 1. Org is SSO Enabled 
 2. User Log says 'Invalid Password' (which isn't true)
 3. this is an internal user. 
 4. Email Deliver-ability is TURNED ON

Summary : We are trying to create a user and extract its password. when i set a password once and then try to use the credential to login in a separate tab, it says invalid user name password, also, forgot password doesn't works. this is for internal users.

Comment: I'm not following. Are they resetting their password in production and then using "test.salesforce.com"? Are you sure you're trying the same sandbox each time. Is email deliverability turned on in the sandbox you're resetting?

Comment: updated question with your remarks, this is a sandbox. basically we are trying to create a user and extract its password. when i set a password once and then try to use the credential to login in a separate tab, it says invalid user name password, also, forgot password doesn't works. this is for internal users.

Comment: did you try login as admin and reset the user password from user sceen, do you receive email in that case?

Comment: Also check the Login IP ranges for the user you're trying to login from.

Comment: both of the methods tried, i tried doing with a non SSO org, it worked out perfectly.